# Importing dump file in Oracle using impdp

Tags: oracle, datapump, impdp

I am facing troubles while using `impdp` in `Oracle 11g`. I am reading the documentation but still am missing some point.

I created a test database, along side with the oracle_home of orcl database. I created the directory as /home/oracle from orcl dabase and granted read write on that directory to hr user, which I wanted to export the schema. Export happened successfully. Then, I quit sql prompt from orcl database, change the oracle_sid (.oraenv and type test_database), and execute

`impdp scott/scott directory=dump_dir dumpfile=hr.emp` it does not work.

What point am I missing? I just want to export hr schema from hr user in orcl database and
import it into scott user from test database.

Thanks.

Comment: What does 'it does not work' mean - what error did you get? Did you create the `DIRECTORY` object in both databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DIRECTORY` object is local to the database; creating it in one database does not make it available to others, even if they share an `ORACLE_HOME`.

You need to repeat your commands in the `test` database before running `impdp`:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dump_dir AS /home/orcl;
GRANT read, write ON dump_dir TO hr;
```

Your import command may also have a mistake; the dump file it probably `hr.dmp` rather than `hr.emp`.